# Focus on next input of selected class even if on another class input with jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, focus

I'm having trouble finding the right code to do this in jQuery.
I can focus on the next input with the '.first' class with this code. But if i'm not on a '.first' input it'll go to the first '.first' input.

This is the code snippet:

```js
 var $first_elements = $('.section .first');
    var $inputs = $('input');
    $inputs.on('keyup', function(e) {
        if (e.which === 13) {
            var ind = $first_elements.index(this);
            $first_elements.eq(ind + 1).focus()
        }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <div class="section">
    <input class="first" name="input_1" /><input name="input_2" /><input name="input_3" />
    <br/>
    <input class="first" name="input_4" /><input name="input_5" /><input name="input_6" />
    <br/>
    <input class="first" name="input_7" /><input name="input_8" /><input name="input_9" />
  </div>
```

How can I go to the next input with the `.first` selector from any input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your code like this, bind keyup event only for the input element which have class `first`

```js
 var $inputs = $('input');
 $inputs.on('keyup', function(e) {
   if (e.which === 13) {
     $inputs.next('input.first').focus()
   }
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="first" name="input_1" />
<input name="input_2" />
<input name="input_3" />
<input class="first" name="input_4" />
<input name="input_5" />
<input name="input_6" />
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this does the opposite. It focuses on the next input if the focus is on a .first element right now.
It should focus on the next .first element if you hit enter from ANY input

Comment: Still works ony if you are on a .first input. It should work from any input

Comment: Thanks! The next() method is really nice. jQuery never fails to amaze me